# Can't change my pointers reference

Tags: c, pointers

I want to declare a pointer, pass it into a function and use that function to allocate memory space for that pointer and to use later.

Can someone help me find out where I went wrong?

```
int main()
{
    float * hostdata=NULL;

    int size = 10;
    randgen(&hostdata, size);
    /* Show result */
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%1.4f ", hostdata[i]);// here goes wrong, i got a exception here.
    }
    free(hostdata);

    return 0;
}

int randgen(float ** host_Data,int size_n) {
    size_t n = size_n;
    size_t i;

    float * hostData = *host_Data;// **I went wrong at this line, i just tell system that , declare a float pointer and it's value is the same value as host_data ,  nothing more. so , hostdata in main function still remain NULL.**

    curandGenerator_t gen;
    float *devData;
    /* Allocate n floats on host */
    hostData = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float)); 
   /* Allocate n floats on device */
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void **)&devData, n * sizeof(float))); 
   /* Create pseudo-random number generator */ 
    CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));
   /* Set seed */ 
    CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL));
   /* Generate n floats on device */
    CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, devData, n)); 
   /* Copy device memory to host */ 
   CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(float), 
  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); 

    /* Cleanup */
    CURAND_CALL(curandDestroyGenerator(gen));
    CUDA_CALL(cudaFree(devData));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what going wrong?

Comment: are you expecting hostdata in main to get updated?

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What are you expecting? Providing a [mcve] is a prerequisite for a good answer.

Comment: the exception is in this line :  printf("%1.4f ", hostdata[i]) ,  where hostdata still remains to NULL, and cause an access to address zero error, so the value of hostdata is not the address that i allocate in the randgen function.

Comment: `hostdata`, `hostData`, and `host_Data`, *really*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like everyone else has said, you should change:

```
hostData = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));
```

to:

```
*host_Data = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));
```

The reason for this is based on the way memory works in C. Each instance of a function is given it's own stack for its variables, which is garbage collected once the instance of the function is finished. This means that any value saved in your `randgen` variables from will be deleted at the end. You pass in the address of the original `hostdata` variable from the main function to your `randgen` function as `host_data` so that you can alter the data inside the original `hostdata` variable from main's stack. Since `hostdata` in main is equal to NULL, setting `hostData` equal to `*host_data`, which is the equivalent of saying "go to the address stored in `host_data` and take that value and save it in `hostData`", makes it also equal to NULL. Then, when you assign the return value of calloc to `hostData`, you are saving that value on the functions's stack, which is then deleted after the function finishes. On the other hand, when you assign the return value of calloc to `*host_data`, you are saying "go to the address stored in `host_data`, which is the address of `hostdata`, and save the value there, so now you have access to the calloced memory in your main function.

Comment: thanks a lot for your patiently words and time,your way it works and lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change

```
hostData = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));
```

to

```
*host_Data = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));
```

And the same thing for CUDA_CALL

Comment: hi rounak, but i already have this line: float * hostData = *host_Data;

Answer (score 0):

if you expect hostdata in main to be updated you need to do

```
 *host_Data = (float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float)); 
 hostData = *host_Data;
```